# how to get lock in svn

Tags: svn, locking

I am a learner of SVN. Now I want to lock a file. I have set the property as svn:needs-lock, then I commited the file. After that I chose "SVN Get lock". But the problem is that it always says Not Implemented!Lock Failed. I am so confused!

Comment: Which Subversion client are you using?

Comment: For new projects or for starting, I recommend `git` today (even for single-developer hobby projects) over `svn`.

Comment: Also, using the command line `svn` client is probably the most powerful and usual way of using Svn. I'm not sure that using only a graphical wrapper above `svn` is good. Start by typing `svn help` in a terminal

Comment: I am using TortoiseSvn. And my server is provided by Google Code for free.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google Code does *not* provide `svn lock` functionality: See [Issue 1349](http://code.google.com/p/support/issues/detail?id=1349), opened in 2008, so don't expect this feature anytime soon.

Comment: Wow! I see! This problem has been puzzling me for a whole afternoon. Thank you for saving me!